# String building with particular pattern using char separator

Tags: c#, string, linq, lambda

I want to have an string in this format

```
 name1,date1|name2,date2
```

For that I have written a method

```
int ifirstStringLength = strFirstStringArray.Length;
int iSecondStringLength = strSecondStringArray.Length;

if (ifirstStringLength != iSecondStringLength)
    throw new Exception("First and Second Array should be of same length");

for (int index = 0; index < ifirstStringLength; index++)
{
     strCombinedString = strCombinedString + strFirstStringArray[index] + chrElementSeprator.ToString() + strSecondStringArray[index];
     if (index < ifirstStringLength - 1)
         strCombinedString = strCombinedString + chrItemSeperator.ToString();
}

return strCombinedString;
```

Question 1:
Is this a good way or any better way?

Question 2:
Any idea if I want to achieve this using linq/lambda expression?

Updated:

my inputs are

```
        string[] names = {"name1","name2"};
        string[] dates = {"date1","date2"};
```

sorry for miscommunication

Comment: `String.Join(strCombinedString, "|")` might work.

Comment: first string will have names and second string will have dates and we want to combine them

Comment: @ShafqatMasood separated my comma?

Comment: yes separated by comma and next item should be separated by |

Comment: Why did you choose the "lambda" tag for this question ? Did you mean LINQ, maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is to split names and dates separately, then zip two sequences, combining name-date pair one at a time. After that join each pair with '|' symbol

```
string[] names = {"name1", "name2"};
string[] dates = {"date1", "date2"};

var pairs = names.Zip(dates, (name, date) => name + "," + date);

string result = string.Join("|", pairs);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

prints:

```
name1,date1|name2,date2
```

Comment: your code works fine if i have inputs as you mentioned..but if i want to use array of names and dates then i dnt work..i think due to misscommunication.so i have voted for you thanks

Comment: @ShafqatMasood what exact **data type** of names and dates are you having?

Comment: thanks it works...but the other guy has already replied using select and join. and you have used zip and join.. any particular reason for using zip. as i have seen this first time..

Comment: @ShafqatMasood it's up to you what to use. Zip will handle gracefully if two arrays will have different `Length`, but `dates[index]` will result in `IndexOutOfRangeException` if there will be more names than dates

Comment: so we forget about the indexoutofrange exception using zip..cool

Comment: finally accept your answer.. for using zip. which will remove my headache of handling exception..

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems needlessly complex to me. Not entirely sure this will meet all of your requirements but I would do something like this;

```
  //assuming both strings are comma delimited
  string[] nameTokens = nameString.Split(',');
  string[] dateTokens = dateString.Split(',');
  string result;
  if (nameTokens.Length == 2 && dateTokens.Length == 2)
      result = String.Format("{1},{2}|{3},{4}", nameTokens[0], dateTokens[0], nameTokens[1], dateTokens[1]);
  else
       Console.WriteLine("BAD INPUT");
```

Explanation; I start by splitting the name and date strings so I have two strings arrays. Then I check the lengths to make sure they each have 2 elements (prevent array out of bounds exceptions). After that I use the `String.Format` method to create a new string in the specified format. There are shorter solutions available using LINQ however, this ensures that you don't get an array out of bounds exception and could not be more straight forward.

Comment: it works for 2 items.. what if i have 100 items..then?? so your code is too much specific.

Comment: @ShafqatMasood your question was too much specific :p  Had you said you needed a method that worked with lists of any size I would have written code that worked for lists of any size.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ's `Select` method. One of the overloads takes a [`Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx). This gives you the index of the current string in the array.

```
var result = string.Join("|", 
    names.Select((s, index) => string.Format("{0},{1}", s, dates[index])));
```

Comment: ur code give me this output n,d|a,a|m,t|e,e|1,1|,,,|n,d|a,a|m,t|e,e|2,2

Answer (score 0):

```
string strCombinedString = strFirstStringArray.Select((S, i) => "|" + S + "," + strSecondStringArray[i]).Aggregate((Result, Item) => Result += Item);
strCombinedString.Remove(0, 1);
```

Comment: ur code give me output like this |n|d|a|a|m|t|e|e|1|1|,|,|n|d|a|a|m|t|e|e|2|2

Comment: Well, I thought you were really using string `Arrays`. Like `string[] strFirstStringArray, strSecondStringArray;`.

Comment: if i use the array your code give me |name1|date1|name2|date2

Comment: Fixed that. Notice the `remove` line to remove the first "|"